# Make sure at least 1 checkbox is checked for multiple groups of checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, checkbox

I have several groups of checkboxes (each with several checkboxes), and I need to use jQuery (or plain old javascript) to make sure that the form can't submit unless at least 1 checkbox from each group of checkboxes is checked. How can I do this? If Group A doesn't have at least one, I'd like to throw an error specifying "please select at least one from Group A", etc etc. Thanks!

Comment: Give all the checkboxes in the same group the same class. Then you can use `$(":checkbox.groupClass:checked").length` to get the number of checkboxes that are checkes in that group. Loop over all the classes, and if any of them are `0` fail the validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle this by defining a CSS class to "group" each of your sets of checkbox elements and then process each group to see if at least one of the elements is checked and alert the user accordingly.

Some example markup might look like the following :

```
<form>
    <pre>Group A</pre>
    <input class='group-a' data-name='Group A' type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
    <input class='group-a' data-name='Group A' type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
    <pre>Group B</pre>
    <input class='group-b' data-name='Group B' type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
    <input class='group-b' data-name='Group B' type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
    <pre>Group C</pre>
    <input class='group-c' data-name='Group C' type='checkbox' value='1' /> 1
    <input class='group-c' data-name='Group C' type='checkbox' value='2' /> 2
    <hr />
    <input type='submit' />
  </form>
```

Along with the following bit of jQuery that will handle your actual logic :

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(e){
           // Store each group that has been processed
            var checkedGroups = [];
            // Check each group 
            $(':checkbox[class^="group-"]').each(function(){
                // Store a reference to the current class
                var currentGroup = $(this).attr('class');
                // If the current group hasn't been checked, check it
                if($.inArray(currentGroup,checkedGroups) == -1){
                    var atLeastOneChecked = $(':checkbox.' + currentGroup + ':checked').length > 0;
                    // If at least one isn't checked, alert the user
                    if(!atLeastOneChecked){
                        // Alert the user and stop everything going forward
                        alert("Please ensure that at least one option from " + $(this).data('name') + " is checked.");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                    // If we have made it this far, then this group has been checked
                    checkedGroups.push(currentGroup);
                }      
            });
        });
    });
  </script>
```

You don't necessarily have to use CSS classes to handle the selection. You could easily use `data-*` attributes to handle that as well, so it's just up to your personal preference.

You can [see an example of this code in action here](http://jsbin.com/sinovaz/edit?html,output).

Comment: This works like a charm! Is there any way to specify the alert without the data-name attribute? My only option is to put the markup directly into the Wordpress text editor, which for some reason is stripping out that attribute. If you're wondering, it's not possible for me (or anyone) to add plugins or edit Wordpress files for this website.

Comment: Nevermind, I just added the attribute to each input with jquery.

Comment: Thank you! You're a life saver